# lyr.datasetName works with "CURRENT" mxd but not with mxd path

Tags: arcpy, layers

I have some mxds in wich I want to set all the layers a layer description. 
This works as far as I use the code with current mxd, but if I give a path it has no results, and I also don't get any error messages.

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:/base/example.mxd")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    lyr.description = "asd"
```

Comment: You need to run the `mxd.save()` in your script as the last step.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @AlexTereshenkov in a comment:

> You need to run the mxd.save() in your script as the last step.

Opening an ArcPy MapDocument object from an MXD using a full pathname to that file is NOT the same as having that MXD open in ArcMap and being referenced as the "CURRENT" map document.

If I open a map document which has no layers in ArcMap, add a layer and run your code using "CURRENT" I would expect to see that layer reported because the current map document object "knows" what has been done to it (i.e. it had a layer added).

If I then open the map document using your code and its full pathname, then I am accessing what that MXD file contained prior to the last save which was performed on it from either ArcMap or using `mxd.save()` from ArcPy.  If no save was performed between adding the layer, and running your code, then I would expect no layers to be reported and I would not expect to get an error.